# Project runs locally but not on server - Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlMode' from assembly System.Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working a little project for myself using ASP.Net MVC 2 Preview 2 and it works great locally but won't run on my dedicated server - I get the following error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlMode' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Looks like it is my:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(model=>model) %>
```

That is causing this error - anyone else running into this and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to control panel --> administrative tools --> net framework configuration --> manage assembly cache --> view list.

can you find System.web there ? .. whats the version ? .. is it correct.

Reinstall .NET framework to be sure you have it installed correctly.

Comment: yep, it matches Verison, Culture, PublicKeyToken.  I do not want to re-install since I have a few very busy ASP.Net MVC 1 sites on this server and I was hoping I could just drop the needed assemblies in the bin directory of this app and have it run just like I did for the MVC 1 Preview 1-5 releases.

Comment: I didn't have .Net 3.5 SP 1 installed on my server